# How to check Sharepoint connectivity before ClientContext.ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am very new to sharepoint. What is the fastest and most efficient way to check Sharepoint site connectivity before ClientContext.ExecuteQuery.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharepoint siteUrl"]);

float pageLoadTime = getPageLoadTime(ctx);
if(pageLoadTime > 0.5)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Sharepoint site is not available!");
  return;
}
//do very heavy query
....
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such standard method to do that. But you can achieve this like following code

```
   using (ClientContext sourceContext = new ClientContext("Sharepoint Url"))
        {
            try
            {                    
                sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
                List list = sourceContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
                ListItemCollection itemColl = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                sourceContext.Load(itemColl);
                sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }                
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SharePoint not available");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }              
        }
```

because "ExecuteQuery" is the method which connect to SharePoint through Client.svc wcf service.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi, Ahshay, Thank you for your answer. Maybe I should use "Ping" to check for connectivity before performing a task.